# remote access to Linux interface

Tags: remote-access

I have a problem: i have a linux pc that i cannot use because is faraway from me. I can connect on its by ssh. I need the graphical interface. I try to use x11, but don't work. I try to use team viewer, but i need the license. Is there anyway that I can remotely access and see Ubuntu interface from my PC? thanks.
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________-

Comment: You are looking for VNC, but this is off-topic, as it's not a programming question (see e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers).

Comment: I know, sorry if I was wrong